# ValueError: Unknown optimizer: RAdam from load_model of Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network, transfer-learning

I have got **"ValueError: Unknown optimizer: RAdam"**
when I ran the following cell.

```
from keras_bert import get_custom_objects
bert_model = load_model("model.h5", custom_objects=get_custom_objects())
```

If I change it to :

```
from keras_bert import get_custom_objects
bert_model = load_model("model.h5", custom_objects={'RAdam': RAdam})
```

I have got **"ValueError: Unknown layer: TokenEmbedding"**

I am using

```
from keras_radam import RAdam
print(tf.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)
1.15.0
2.2.4
```

Any advice regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to import and put "TokenEmbedding" to the custom_objects dict?